# Heading items to tree structure with missing items

Tags: javascript

I am writing a function that queries all heading elements that are direct children of a div and stores them as an item in an *array* (`data`) where a heading with a lower tag name is an `item` of the heading above it. In other words, creating a tree structure for the headings. Each heading is in the `data` array is an *object* with the following properties:

`text` : a *string* with the inner text of the heading.

`items`: an *array* with possible subheading items.

`number`: a *string* that represents the position of the heading in the document.

`id`: a *string* that is composed of the text of the element and it's parents texts, separated by two underscores "__".

Getting the names and numbers right, I had to store the last ones for each heading level in an array, to access them while traversing through the items. This is what I came up with:

```js
const contentContainer = document.getElementById('content');
// Query headings that are direct children of the content container. 
const headings = contentContainer.querySelectorAll(":scope > h1,:scope > h2,:scope > h3,:scope > h4,:scope > h5,:scope > h6");

// String helper function
function kebabCase(string) {
  return (string
    .replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').replace(/[\s_]+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
  )
}

// Contains the list of headings and their items.
const data = [];
// Array that stores the last depth of each of the last headings at each depth.
const indexHelper = new Array(6).fill(-1);
// Array that stores the last name of each of the last headings at each depth.
const nameHelper = new Array(6).fill('');

// Generates a datalist of headings and sets an id for each heading in the DOM.
function processTag(depth, element) {
  const listItem = {
    text: element.innerText,
    items: []
  };
  const name = kebabCase(element.innerText);
  // Increment the indexHelper at depth position and set the current name.
  indexHelper[depth]++;
  nameHelper[depth] = name;
  // Reset rest of array that is bigger than current depth.
  indexHelper.fill(-1, depth + 1);
  // Push the element to the right place in the array.
  let dataPushString = 'data';
  for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    dataPushString += "[indexHelper[".concat(i, "]]?.items?");
    i < depth - 1 && (dataPushString += '.');
  }
  dataPushString += '.push(listItem)';
  eval(dataPushString);
  // Generate an id based on the names of the element and its parents.
  let id = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    id += nameHelper[i] + "__";
  }
  let number = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    number += "(indexHelper[".concat(i + 1, "] +1) + \".\" ");
    i < depth - 1 && (number += ' + ');
  }

  listItem.id = id + name;
  listItem.number = eval(number) && eval(number);
}

function processData() {
  for (let i = 0; i < headings.length; i++) {
    const element = headings[i];
    const depth = Number(element.tagName.substring(1) - 1);
    processTag(depth, element);
  }
}

processData();

const pre = document.getElementById('pre');
pre.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
      <h3>This heading is problematic</h3>
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <h2>Another h2</h2>
      <h3>Depth h3 </h3>
        <h4>Fourth level</h4>
      <h3>Back to three</h3>
    <h2>Back to two</h2>
</div>
```

As you can see in the example above, the malformatted `<h3>This heading is problematic</h3>` not added to `data`. The reason being, I am looping over the item and try to add it to it's parent that does not exist. This is done by creating concatenating a *string* to the right "depth" using eval(), which also is a [bad idea](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#never_use_eval!).

**My question is twofold:** how can I make sure the problematic heading is added to `data` even though it's (direct) parent heading does not exist? And how do I get around not using eval()?

The result I am hoping to get is:

```
[
  {
    "text": "Title",
    "items": [
      {
        "text": "",
        "items": [
           {
            "text": "This heading is problematic",
            "items": [],
            "id": "title____this-heading-is-problematic",
            "number": "2.1.1"
           },
       ],
        "id": "title__",
        "number": "1."
      },
      {
        "text": "H2",
        "items": [],
        "id": "title__h2",
        "number": "2."
      },
      {
        "text": "Another h2",
        "items": [
               //...etc...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your code can be simplified.

All you need is a single stack, where the top item is the current parent *candidate*, i.e. "the last heading we encountered". For every heading we encounter, as many items are popped off the stack as are necessary so that the new heading can logically fit beneath. Then the new heading is pushed onto the stack, wash, rinse, repeat.

```js
const kebabCase = s => s.replace(/([a-z])([A-Z])/g, '$1-$2').replace(/[\s_]+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

const headings = document.querySelector('#content').querySelectorAll('h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6');
const stack = [{text: 'root', level: 0, items:[]}];

[...headings].forEach(h => {
    const self = {
        text: h.textContent.trim(),
        level: +h.nodeName.replace('H', ''),
        items: [],
    };
    while (self.level <= stack[stack.length-1].level) stack.pop();
    stack[stack.length-1].items.push(self);
    stack.push(self);

    self.ord = stack[stack.length-2].items.length;
    self.num = stack.map(i => i.ord).slice(1).join('.') + '.';
    self.id = stack.map(i => kebabCase(i.text)).slice(1).join('__');
});

document.querySelector('#pre').textContent = JSON.stringify(stack[0].items, null, 2);
```

```html
<pre id="pre"></pre>

<div id="content">
  <h1>Title</h1>
      <h3>This heading is problematic</h3>
    <h2>H2</h2>
    <h2>Another h2</h2>
      <h3>Depth h3 </h3>
        <h4>Fourth level</h4>
      <h3>Back to three</h3>
    <h2>Back to two</h2>
</div>
```

Of course, outline numbering is a matter of definition when the heading hierarchy is incorrect to begin with.

Comment: What an incredibly elegant solution. One question: would it ever make sense to separate the stack from a different array where you push the data to in your loop, or does this create unnecessary complexion?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Hm... assuming that I imagine the same thing as you do, I don't think that would bring an improvement.

Comment: What I had in mind is creating two empty arrays, `stack` and `data`. And then use: 
`while (self.level <= stack[stack.length - 1]?.level && stack.length > 1) stack.pop();
stack.length < 1 ? data.push(self) : stack[stack.length - 1].items.push(self);` You can remove the `slice()` and it makes sure to set the first heading as the parent regardless of what tag was used. Not really a big difference:  https://jsfiddle.net/dirkjf/jto4dywe/

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber Yeah, I thought you'd mean something like this. I think it's less clean, the second array is not really necessary and being able to lose the `.slice(1)` is too little an improvement overall, I would say.